# How to maintain consistent speeds going up and down slopes

Tags: godot

So I'm using move_and_slide_with_snap to make sure that I don't have a 'bumpy' ride down slopes, but it seems like when moving up and down slopes, my character moves up slopes slower, and moves down slopes faster than when they're on flat ground even when I'm not applying gravity. One would think snap would stop this from occurring, but it happens anyways. Here's my relevant code:

```
# Jumping & Gravity
    var snap = Vector3()
    if is_on_floor() or (is_on_floor() and is_on_wall()):
        snap = -get_floor_normal()
        gravity_vec = Vector3.ZERO
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
            snap = Vector3.ZERO
            gravity_vec = Vector3.UP * jump_power
    elif not is_on_floor():
        player_state = "In Air"
        snap = Vector3.ZERO
        gravity_vec += Vector3.DOWN * gravity * delta
        if is_on_ceiling():
            gravity_vec = Vector3.DOWN * gravity * delta

# Acceleration & Air Movement
    direction = direction.normalized()
    var current_acceleration: float
    if is_on_floor() and direction.dot(h_velocity) > 0:
        current_acceleration = acceleration
    else:
        current_acceleration = deacceleration
    if not is_on_floor():
        current_acceleration *= air_control
    
    h_velocity = h_velocity.linear_interpolate(direction * player_speed, current_acceleration * delta)
    velocity.x = h_velocity.x + gravity_vec.x
    velocity.z = h_velocity.z + gravity_vec.z
    velocity.y = gravity_vec.y
    
    velocity = move_and_slide_with_snap(velocity, snap, Vector3.UP, true, 4, max_slope_angle)
```